# Where to find out when Facebook APIs become available to all users?

Tags: facebook, messaging, facebook-fql

I've been writing a small Facebook app which uses the unified_thread table using FQL. According to the documentation at [the unified_thread documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_thread/) the new messaging system is coming to all users. Where is it announced when that will happen? Is there some canonical resource by Facebook where they have some form of roadmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your wish will be granted on Nov 30th, 2011: [Steps Toward the New Messaging System](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/591/)

Also, here is a direct link to the Facebook Dev Roadmap: [Developer Roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)